# Toggle Play / Pause Buttons in HTML Audio Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

I am after a very basic music player, I have the following basics working now, however;

1) How to make both the Play and Pause buttons in one button? That appears first as Pause and on click It toggles Play and on click again it Toggle Pause?

2) Also Is there anyway to add a progress counter? not a bar, but numbers i.e. 0.3/4.0min

**Here is the fiddle: [www.jsfiddle.net/tjHhY](http://jsfiddle.net/tjHhY/)
And here is the code as well here:**

```
var audio = new Audio("http://dp0169.free.fr/Musique/Air/Air%20-%20Talkie%20Walkie/02%20Cherry%20Blossom%20Girl.mp3");

$(".play").click(function () {
    audio.play();
})

$(".pause").click(function () {
    audio.pause();
})
```

Comment: The play and pause button should also be reference by ID not class. I.E. `$("#play").click....`

`<input type="button" id="play" />`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use JQueryUI. It have nice variety of widgets to create clean interface :)

Also check this [demo](http://jqueryui.com/button/#toolbar) it shows how to create toggle play & pause button.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check this [Demo](http://demo.ftutorials.com/html5-audio/). Hope it helps :)